# Morgan is not logging the rest api calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, logging, morgan

I am creating a express app in which morgan is using for the logging. But I am not able to see the logs while running the app. What should I do to get the logs properly using morgan in express app?

These are the snippets where I am enabling the morgan.

```
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');

let routes = require('./router');

const app = express();

morgan.format('myFormat', '[:date[clf]] ":method :url" :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms');
app.use(morgan('myFormat'));
```

I also tried to run it with dev environment like

```
app.use(logger('dev'));
```

What can I do for getting the logs properly in my express app?

Comment: try `app.use(morgan('dev'));`

Comment: tried this as well. app.use(morgan('dev'));. but still not printing any logs.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reorder the lines, like this:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const morgan = require('morgan');

morgan.format('myFormat', '[:date[clf]] ":method :url" :status :res[content-length] - :response-time ms');

app.use(morgan('tiny')); 

let routes = require('./router');
```